# What is $\mathbb{R}^+$

Tags: notation, real-numbers

Well some books refer to $\mathbb{R}^+$ to be the set of all positive real numbers while others say $\mathbb{R}^+$ is a set of non-negative real number.

Is there a universally accepted definition for the term $\mathbb{R}^+$, i.e. is $0\in \mathbb{R}^+$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you have answered your own question when you say

> some books refer to $\mathbb{R}^+$ to be the set of all positive real numbers
>   while others say $\mathbb{R}^+$ is a set of non-negative real number.

It would seem that there isn't a universal definition since some books use one definition for the notation and other books use another definition.

That said, by far the most sources that I have come across would say that $\mathbb{R}^+$ is the set of all (strictly) positive numbers and so it does not include $0$.

Comment: The same  for $\mathbb Z^+$ and $\mathbb Q^+$.

Answer (score 2):

The notation $\mathbb R^+$  denotes the set of positive real numbers, that is: $$\mathbb R^+ = \{x\in\mathbb R\mid x>0\}$$

The other set, $\mathbb R^-$, denotes the set of negative real numbers.The terminology you state, that is *non-negative* real numbers and whether $0 \in \mathbb{R}^{+}$ wholly depends on the choice person using the notation chooses: sometimes it does, sometimes it doesn't.